# Bloomberg function for CDS ticker

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I want to pull the historical price data for a couple of CDS tickers. But the excel formula `=BDP()`is not working at all.

For e.g. I want to pull price data for `BKIR CDS EUR SR 5Y Corp` which is the name of a CDS of Bank of Ireland. I am using
`=BDH("BKIR CDS EUR SR 5Y Corp","px last","21/10/2015","21/10/2015")`. But it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: First, you say `=BDP()` is not working, but your example is `=BDH()` - which is it? Second, when you say 'it is not working' - what do you mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: Hey sorry for the inconsistency. Anyway I used the Help function and they told me that the data supplier 'CMAN' prohibits excel formula data pulling for non-subscribers. Thanks for your help!